# A linearly ordered set endowed with the order topology is compact if and only if it has no gap.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

The following is written on Wikipedia's article on Dedekind cut, §Arbitrary linearly ordered sets. ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut#Arbitrary_linearly_ordered_sets))

> In the general case of an arbitrary linearly ordered set $X$, a cut is a pair $(A, B)$ such that $A ∪ B = X$ and $a ∈ A$, $b ∈ B$ imply $a < b$. Some authors add the requirement that both $A$ and $B$ are nonempty.[<sup>[5]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut#cite_note-5)
>
> If neither $A$ has a maximum, nor $B$ has a minimum, the cut is called a gap. A linearly ordered set endowed with the order topology is compact if and only if it has no gap.[<sup>[6]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut#cite_note-6)

$\mathbb{R}$ is not compact, which means that it has a gap, according to the last line of the quotation. But I don't think that this is true, since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. Any cut of $\mathbb{R}$ either has a maximal element of $A$, or a minimal element of $B$, i.e. any cut of $\mathbb{R}$ has to be either of the form $(-\infty, x) \cup [x, +\infty)$ or $(-\infty, x] \cup (x, +\infty)$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that we **do not** in this setting assume $A$ and $B$ are both nonempty!
This means that (for example) $A=\mathbb{R},B=\emptyset$ is a gap. (Note in particular that "Every element of $A$ is $<$ every element of $B$" is vacuously true in this case.)

As wikipedia says, some texts do require elements of a gap to be nonempty. In that case the right theorem is:

> A linear order $L$ is compact with the order topology iff $L$ has no gaps and $L$ has a greatest element and a least element.